# Thorax collections: childView of ItemView is inheriting next itemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This problem is a bit hard to explain, but I'll give it a try. When I'm using a nested view inside an ItemView of a CollectionView the next ItemView will append inside the previous childView.

```
<div id="items">
    {{#collection}}
        <div class="item">
            {{title}}
            {{view childView}}
        </div>
    {{/collection}}
</div>
```

Results in:

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
         The title
         <div class="childView">
              This is the childView..

               <div class="item">
                   The title
                   <div class="childView">
                         This is the childView..
                   </div>
               </div>
               // And so on...
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like the collectionView is keeping a reference to the last view there was something inserted into. So in this case the childView of the itemView, but it should be the itemView.

I hope I made myself a bit clear, because it is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known [thorax bug](https://github.com/walmartlabs/thorax/issues/159) that was closed.

I would double check your templates and make sure all your html elements have closing tags. Also get the latest version of thorax (assuming there are no breaking changes). It could be that the bug was closed incorrectly and still a problem.